# how to use flask-admin for editing modelview

Tags: flask-admin

How to set password_hash using generate_password_hash from the edit page of flask-admin

1. i create a username and password in python shell. the password is hashing
2. admin.add_view(MyModelView(User, db.session) - let me edit the User class Models
3. when i edit the password and submit but the password is saved in plain text.

How to edit password from flask-admin, the password should be save in hashing type

My code is:

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
class User(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     email = db.Column(db.String(120))
     password_hash = db.Column(db.String(64))
     username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)

     @password.setter
     def password(self, password):
          self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

     def __repr__(self):
          return '<User %r>' % self.username

#Create custom models view
class MyModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    @admin.expose('/login/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('login.html')

# Create custom admin view
class MyAdminView(admin.BaseView):
    @admin.expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('myadmin.html')

admin = admin.Admin(name="Simple Views")
admin.add_view(MyAdminView(name='hello'))
admin.add_view(MyModelView(User, db.session))
admin.init_app(app)
app.run()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i solved my problem by using on_model_change function in flask-admin

```
#Create custom models view
class MyModelView(sqla.ModelView):
    @admin.expose('/login/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('login.html')
    def on_model_change(self, form, User, is_created=False):
        User.password = form.password_hash.data
```

Comment: Be warned that if password is already set then you will get password hash prefilled in your form, which after submitting will be re-hashed corrupting actual password. See my answer for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 8):

Alternative solution is to subclass a `TextField` adding custom processing logic:

```
class MyPassField(TextField):
    def process_data(self, value):
        self.data = ''  # even if password is already set, don't show hash here
        # or else it will be double-hashed on save
        self.orig_hash = value

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        value = ''
        if valuelist:
            value = valuelist[0]
        if value:
            self.data = generate_password_hash(value)
        else:
            self.data = self.orig_hash

class UserView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(
        passhash=MyPassField,
    )
    form_widget_args = dict(
        passhash=dict(
            placeholder='Enter new password here to change password',
        ),
    )
```

Comment: def process_fromdata -> def process_formdata

Answer (score 3):

Simpler solution, you don't need to subclass `TextField`

Just add `on_form_prefill` :

```
def on_model_change(self, form, User, is_created):
    if form.password_hash.data:
        User.set_password(form.password_hash.data)
    else:
        del form.password_hash

def on_form_prefill(self, form, id):
    form.password_hash.data = ''
```

This will prevent double-hashing.

Comment: What is the reason to ``del``ete `form.password_hash` field object in your `on_model_change`?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solutions outlined in some of the other answers and I was only partially successful. There were issues with being able to edit the user later, and the password rehashing, or disappearing altogether.

One discovery I made was that `on_model_change` actually gets called AFTER the model is populated from the form. There is no way to access the old values of the model without querying the database or monkey patching `update_model`.

I have come up with a simpler version (I believe) that works in all scenarios.

Here is the whole view:

```
class UserView(AdminModel):
    can_create = True
    column_list = ('name', 'email',)
    column_searchable_list = ('name', 'email',)
    form_excluded_columns = ('password',)
    form_extra_fields = {
        'set_password': PasswordField('Set New Password')
    }

    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        if is_created:
            model.active = True
            model.pending = False
        if form.email.data:
            # Strip spaces from the email
            form.email = form.email.data.strip()
        if form.set_password.data:
            model.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.set_password.data.strip())

    def __init__(self, session, **kwargs):
        # You can pass name and other parameters if you want to
        super(UserView, self).__init__(User, session, **kwargs)
```

What I did was add a form field `set_password` which when populated creates a password hash and updates `password` on the model.

One and done!

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to simply add the column formatters field to the UserView model which  returns a dict of all the form fields .then chose to format the password being saved with a bcrypt hash.

```
class UserView(ModelView):
        column_formatters =dict(password=lambda v,c,m,password: bcrypt.generate_password_hash(m.password, config.get('BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS')) \
                .decode('utf-8'))
```

for more details on the arguments the lambdafunction takes ,the official flaskAdmin docs .[column_formatters](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.6/api/mod_model/#flask.ext.admin.model.BaseModelView.column_formatters)